# Why does the preview open if i put ['Search: '-print``-''] in an object?

Tags: javascript, security, printing, preview

If I write ``` ['Search: '-print``-''] ``` in the browser console and enter, the print preview opens.
Whaaaat!
Can anyone explain this strange behavior to me (perhaps it's only strange for me?) and if possible tell me if there are others? Thank you very much..

I tryed to sanyfing this but I can't do it well without knowing the cause is this event.

Comment: Same reason as if you type `print \`\`` *(but without the syntactically-correct-but-semantically-insane string math as an array element)*. See also [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates).

Comment: There are definitely other strange JS behaviors; search for "js wat" if nothing else, but there's more than that.